# How to convert [0,3,4] into 100110 that is 6 digit string format in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, format

How to convert [0,3,4] into 100110 that is 6 digit string  format in SQL Server  2012 ?

Example

```
string  [2,4,5]
```

should be converted into

```
string 001011
```

I have to make 6 digit string , and the digit or position in the string 000000 should be convert to 1 suppose in above string [2,4,5] means 2nd ,4th and 5th index of 000000 should be converted to 1. Final string should be 001011

[image]

Comment: What is the logic beneath converting `[0,3,4]` into `100110`? Please? add some details.

Comment: @gofr1 - Question Edited with explanation

Comment: Thanks! One more question. How this string is stored? Just a `varchar` column with `[0,3,4]`?

Comment: @gofr1 - old string  format is varchar(max) , We can strore new valuel ike 100110 in any sql column format

Comment: And how this string is stored now? Can you add some sample of data in that column? Or how do you get this string (like `[2,4,5]`)?

Comment: @gofr1 - please check now, The data collected already in that original format column , I have to convert that column like column B

Comment: Now it is all clear! Thanks! Check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @zero_str VARCHAR(6) = '000000'
-- Generate table alike to yours    
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (
    [value] varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES ('[2,4,5]'),('[0,3,4]' )
-- convert array to xml
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  [value],
            CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING([value],2,LEN([value]) - 2),',','</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml) as x
    FROM @yourTable
)
-- do the stuff
SELECT  c.[value],
        RIGHT(@zero_str + CAST(SUM(CAST(STUFF(@zero_str,t.c.value('.','tinyint')+1,1,'1') as int)) as varchar(6)),6 )
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/a') as t(c)
GROUP BY c.[value]
```

Output:

```
value   (No column name)
[0,3,4] 100110
[2,4,5] 001011
```

Explanation:

`STUFF(@zero_str,t.c.value('.','tinyint')+1,1,'1')` This changes some part of `000000` to `1`, after this part we will have:

```
[2,4,5] 001000
[2,4,5] 000010
[2,4,5] 000001
[0,3,4] 100000
[0,3,4] 000100
[0,3,4] 000010
```

In the table. Then we do CASTing to `int`? so we can use `SUM`, after this data will be like:

```
[0,3,4] 100110
[2,4,5] 1011
```

Then we add `000000` string and use RIGHT to get only 6 symbols.

Hope that helps!

**Note:**

If no id's in a table then use ROW_NUMBER in CTE part.

```
DECLARE @zero_str VARCHAR(6) = '000000'
-- Generate table alike to yours    
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (
    [value] varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES ('[2,4,5]'),('[0,3,4]'),('[2,3,4]'),('[2,4,5]'),('[0,3,4]'),('[2,3,4]')
-- convert array to xml
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn,
            [value],
            CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING([value],2,LEN([value]) - 2),',','</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml) as x
    FROM @yourTable
)
-- do the stuff
SELECT  c.rn,
        c.[value],
        RIGHT(@zero_str + CAST(SUM(CAST(STUFF(@zero_str,t.c.value('.','tinyint')+1,1,'1') as int)) as varchar(6)),6 )
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/a') as t(c)
GROUP BY c.rn, c.[value]
```

Output:

```
rn  value   (No column name)
2   [0,3,4] 100110
5   [0,3,4] 100110
3   [2,3,4] 001110
6   [2,3,4] 001110
1   [2,4,5] 001011
4   [2,4,5] 001011
```

Comment: Yes your answer is working , I am facing one issue if there are same values in table,or appeared suppose twice [2,3,4] then answer  is coming like 022200

Comment: I get you. There is no any ids in a table?

Comment: If no ids - then ROW_NUMBER, see note to my answer. If ids - add them to CTE-part and in GROUP BY part

Answer (score 3):

You could try `PARSENAME()` function starts from `SQL Server 2012`

```
DECLARE @DATA1 VARCHAR(6) = '000000'

SELECT      A.DATA [Original String],
            STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@DATA1, [First]+1, 1, '1'), [Second]+1 , 1, '1'), [Third]+1, 1, '1') [Converted String] FROM 
(
    SELECT DATA, PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA, '[', ''), ']',''), ',', '.'),3) [First], PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA, '[', ''), ']',''), ',', '.'),2) [Second], PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA, '[', ''), ']',''), ',', '.'),1) [Third] FROM <table_name>
) A
```

Result :

```
 Original String    Converted String
 [0, 3, 4]          100110
 [1, 3, 4]          010110
```

You could learn `Parsename()` function.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql